# How to fix " PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform" in Unity for the Android / OculusGo platform

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, cryptography, endpoint, opc-ua

In my App I try to connect to a OpcUa server. In the Unity Editor mode the connection works as expected but when building for Android and running the App I get the following error:

```
PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
08-13 19:10:13.635  8047  8071 E Unity   :   at Opc.Ua.Bindings.BufferManager..ctor (System.String name, System.Int32 maxPoolSize, System.Int32 maxBufferSize) [0x0001a] in <47abe48abf58405785b9c72f0d4f7649>:0
08-13 19:10:13.635  8047  8071 E Unity   :   at Opc.Ua.Bindings.UaSCUaBinaryTransportChannel.SaveSettings (System.Uri url, Opc.Ua.TransportChannelSettings settings) [0x001a6] in <47abe48abf58405785b9c72f0d4f7649>:0
08-13 19:10:13.635  8047  8071 E Unity   :   at Opc.Ua.Bindings.UaSCUaBinaryTransportChannel.Initialize (System.Uri url, Opc.Ua.TransportChannelSettings settings) [0x00001] in <47abe48abf58405785b9c72f0d4f7649>:0
08-13 19:10:13.635  8047  8071 E Unity   :   at Opc.Ua.WcfChannelBase.CreateUaBinaryChannel (Opc.Ua.ApplicationConfiguration configuration, Opc.Ua.EndpointDescription description, Opc.Ua.EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 clientCertificate, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection clientCertificateChain, Opc.Ua.ServiceMessageContext messageContext) [0x00156] in <47abe48ab
```

which I think is triggered by the line:

```
endpointDescription = CoreClientUtils.SelectEndpoint(endpointURL, UseSecurity, ConnectTimeout);
```

Unfortunately I can't find in the Solution Explorer any file containing "UaSCUaBinaryTransportChannel", "maxpoolsize" or other keywords contained in the error so I don't know how to debbug it...

The project configurations are mono with .NET Core 2
I would be very grateful for every ideas, Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean .NET Core 2 ?

In this case the BufferManager class is not available.

> PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this
> platform.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.buffermanager?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-2.0

Comment: Thank you @Camille G. ! Yes I mean .NET Core 2, just edited the post. Is there a method to transfer the Buffer function on Android? On the link it says the BufferManager is available only on .NET Core 1.1 and 1.0 but in my case it works on 2 in the Editor?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me is sometimes different, keep in mind I'm working with an IL2CPP build (not mono).

- clean build, try again
- reset files via `git checkout -- NativeAndroidApp/.`